# How to Define a Maximum Height for a tikz decision Node

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am using tikzpicture to draw a sequence diagram and ended up with a decision node that looked too high.

[image: diagram where the decision node is too tall]

Is there any way I can make this node a bit shorter? I noticed there's no maximum height attribute, thus the question.

Here is my settings of the decision node:

```
\tikzstyle{decision} = [diamond, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, text width=3cm, draw=black, fill=green!30]
```

And here is the code for drawing the diagram:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm]

  \node (start) [startstop] {Start};
  \node (init) [io, below of=start] {Initialize};
  \node (schedule) [process, below of=init] {schedule(freq, [times])};
  \node (rd) [process, below of=schedule] {record\_data(records, new\_record)};
  \node (dec1) [decision, below of=rd, yshift=-0.5cm] {stressed yesterday?};
  \node (pro2a) [process, below of=dec1, yshift=-0.5cm] {Process 2a};
  \node (pro2b) [process, right of=dec1, xshift=3.5cm] {Process 2b};
  \node (out1) [io, below of=pro2a] {Output};
  \node (stop) [startstop, below of=out1] {Stop};

  \draw [arrow] (start) -- (init);
  \draw [arrow] (init) -- node[anchor=east] {freq=3} (schedule);
  \draw [arrow] (schedule) -- (rd);
  \draw [arrow] (rd) -- (dec1);
  \draw [arrow] (dec1) -- node[anchor=east] {yes} (pro2a);
  \draw [arrow] (dec1) -- node[anchor=south] {no} (pro2b);
  \draw [arrow] (pro2b) |- (schedule);
  \draw [arrow] (pro2a) -- (out1);
  \draw [arrow] (out1) -- (stop);

\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Welcome! If you already know that there is no maximum height attribute, why do you ask the question this way? As you say, there is none. You can add a negative `inner sep` here but better advices can be given if you provide us with the code that produced the output.

Comment: In addition to Schrödinger's cat comment, in such situations a relative positioning of the nodes genreally avoids this kind of issues.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat because restricting the height of a box is sensible to me, and not having such an attribute doesn't imply what I asked in the question is potentially impossible.

Comment: If you post a picture of the result, do you expect others to create a code that produces this picture from scratch to show you their ways of solving the problem? Add a minimal working example that can be used for answers.

Answer (score 1):

After almost two years (sorry, I didn't see question before), probably to late for OP but may help someone else.

As is already noted in comments, in `tikz` is not possible to define maksimum height of of any nodes' shapes. However, some works around to solve OP problem is still possible.

As mentioned in @Jakub G answer, decision node can be flatten by option `aspect=<amount>`. At this one should be aware, that at same time node become wider. So, a some compromise should be find. For example manually split node's text into two lines and select `aspect=1.3`.

But from showed image can be concluded that this have not be main OP problem. He may be happy with `decision` node size, if distance between nodes has been managed correctly. For example by use of the `positioning` library and use its syntax `below=of <node name>` can be defined distance between nodes borders (consequently decision node wouldn't oerlape adjacent nodes) and not between nodes centers as is done at deprecate syntax `below of=<node name>` and consequently when selected distance is to small, it overlap adjacent nodes.

MWE below make such compromise. For aspect is used value 1.3` and for distances between borders of nodes 6mm. Added is common nodes' styles definition which can be used at any flowcharts with the same type of nodes and enables writting concise and short flowchart code.

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                chains,
                positioning,
                quotes,
                shapes.geometric}              
\makeatletter
\tikzset{FlowChart/.style={
suspend join/.code = {\def\tikz@after@path{}},
     base/.style = {draw, fill=##1,
                    minimum height=9mm, text width=36mm,
                    align=center,
                    on chain, join=by arr
                   },
startstop/.style = {base=red!30},
  process/.style = {base=orange!30, rounded corners},
 decision/.style = {diamond, aspect=1.3, inner xsep=0pt,
                    draw, fill=green!30, align=center,  % since not use "base"
                    on chain, join=by arr},             % since not use "base"
       io/.style = {base=blue!30, trapezium, trapezium stretches body,
                    trapezium left angle=70, trapezium right angle=110},
      arr/.style = {semithick,-Triangle},
every edge quotes/.style = {auto, font=\footnotesize}
       }   }
\makeatletter

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[FlowChart,
node distance = 6mm and 12mm,
  start chain = going below,
                        ]
\node (start) [startstop] {Start};
\node (init)  [io]        {Initialize};
\node (schedule) [process]{schedule (freq, [times])};
\node (rd)    [process]   {record\_data\\ (records, new\_record)};
\node (dec1)  [decision]  {stressed\\ yesterday?};
\node (pro2a) [process]   {Process 2a};
\node (out1)  [io]        {Output};
\node (stop)  [startstop] {Stop};

\node (pro2b) [process, suspend join,
               right=of dec1] {Process 2b};
               
\path   (init) edge ["freq=3"]  (schedule)
        (dec1) edge ["yes"]     (pro2a)
        (dec1) edge [arr, "no"] (pro2b);
\draw[arr] (pro2b) |- (schedule);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]